# SAP NetWeaver issue

Tags: java, netweaver

I am getting the below error why running a webservice in Netweaver.

This issue is only in Quality system,I am given the same parameters in Preprod,Development it is giving an output.

There is some issue with Netweaver Quality system configuration.

Don't know what to do. Please help.

Error:

> Server Exception: javax.ejb.EJBException: ASJ.ejb.005044 (Failed in
>   component: synergy.com/synergy~wssear) Exception raised from
>   invocation of public com.synergy.wss.data.response.GasRecordsResponse
>   com.synergy.wss.ejb.IntervalRecordsBean.getGasIntervalData(com.synergy.wss.data.request.DeviceDataRequest)
>   method on bean instance
>   com.synergy.wss.ejb.IntervalRecordsBean@237a5c18 for bean
>   synergy.com/synergy~wssear*xml|synergy.com~synergy~wssejb.jar*xml|IntervalRecordsBean
>   in application synergy.com/synergy~wssear.; nested exception is:
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException; 
>   com.sap.engine.services.webservices.espbase.client.bindings.impl.SOAPTransportBinding.processFault(SOAPTransportBinding.java:2037)
>   ... 75 more

Comment: Refer https://scn.sap.com/thread/3654362. Might help you.

Comment: no luck.this link was not helpful